# ng-click is not working in kendo editor

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-editor

I'm trying to insert an html tag with ng-click event in the kendo editor. When I get the inserted data and show in a div, ng-click is not working. The normal onclick in javascript is working fine, but ng-click is not.

The below given is the `<a>` tag inserted on the editor text area.

`<a ng-click="testMsg()"><span>' + nodeId + '</span></a>`

Any idea on how to resolve this ?

Comment: I don't know how to create this in plunkr. This is just a direct scenario, rt? Let me know if you need any more clarifications.

Comment: The function is being called at all, correct?

Comment: share your controller so I will help you

Comment: Yes. ng-click is not firing at all. For testing, I have added an alert(). This is working if we change it to simple onclick().

Comment: I'm afraid that I could not post the entire controller code here. :(

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` is DOM native event handler but `ng-click` isn't. Only those functions that are registered in the scope will be available. Any built-in functions will NOT be available to `ng-click` without an explicit assignment to the scope as my example shows.

```js
var app = angular.module('app1', []);
app.controller('ctrl1', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  function testMsg() {
    alert('Hello world');
  }
  
  $scope.goodTestMsg = testMsg;
}]);
```

```html
<div ng-app="app1" ng-controller="ctrl1">
  <p ng-click="goodTestMsg()">Click me will show a message</p>
  <p ng-click="testMsg()">Click me should happen nothing</p>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

**TL;DR:** The method `testMsg` is not exposed to the controller scope. Try adding something like `$scope.testMsg = testMsg;` will solve your problem.

Comment: Its not only about the controller, even if I tried a simple alert(), its not working. That event is not triggering. If we change to javascript's onclick, then alert() pops up.

Comment: Html tag is inserted to the editor content using a popup. After inserting into the editor textarea, how will we make sure that the ng-click event is within the scope ? The method which is called 'TestMsg()' is already added in the controller. Do we need to compile or something to bring the updated html's ng-click to the scope ? I have even tried `$compile(customHtml)($scope);` which didn't worked!

Comment: Compilation worked successfully atlast. But the method is not calling correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of textarea, try using div. I am facing similar problem which was partially solved with div. However it will be inline editing as the toolbar will get hidden and it will be displayed only when you focus cursor on the div.